# How to make an image dll file in windows8

Tags: dll, windows-8

I have searched on google and bing, but didn't find any helpful resource. I want to make a dll which contains some images. Anyone can guide me?

Comment: If the below answer presented a solution to your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried here [How to Store Bitmap 
Images in a DLL with Dev-C++](http://www.jpmartel.com/bu21dll.htm)